# Mock a method inside autowired component using Spring, JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I'm looking for a way to "mock" a method inside an Autowired component.

For example, my `PersistService` contains a method like:

```java
@Autowired
    MeterManagementService meterManagementService;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void doPersist(HouseholdUpdateServiceCall householdUpdateServiceCall) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("doPersist start()");
        if (householdUpdateServiceCall.getHhId() > -1) {
            saveUboPanelInfo(householdUpdateServiceCall);
            saveUboSites(householdUpdateServiceCall);
            if (householdUpdateServiceCall.getHouseholdUpdateRequest() != null
                    && householdUpdateServiceCall.getHouseholdUpdateRequest().getPeopleMeter() != null
                    && householdUpdateServiceCall.getHouseholdUpdateRequest().getPeopleMeter().getPeople() != null
                    && householdUpdateServiceCall.getHouseholdUpdateRequest().getPeopleMeter().getPeople().getPerson() != null) {

                Integer panelId = new Long(householdUpdateServiceCall.getPanelId()).intValue();
                Integer hhId = new Long(householdUpdateServiceCall.getHhId()).intValue();
                Integer personCount = householdUpdateServiceCall.getHouseholdUpdateRequest().getPeopleMeter().getPeople().getPerson().size();

                LOG.info("storePersonCount for panelId: " + panelId + ", hhId: " + hhId + ", personCount: " + personCount);
                uboPanelDao.storePersonCount(hhId, personCount, panelId);
            }

        String result = meterManagementService.getResult();
        LOG.info("The result is: " + result);     
        LOG.info("doPersist end()");
        }
    }
```

The Junit test contains:

```
    @Autowired
    PersistService persistService;

    //normal success scenario
    @Test
    public void test03() {
        try {
            HouseholdUpdateServiceCall householdUpdateServiceCall = new HouseholdUpdateServiceCall();
            householdUpdateServiceCall.setCPCount(0);
            householdUpdateServiceCall.setHhId(1L);
            householdUpdateServiceCall.setPanelId(1L);


            //how to mock the method which is used inside doPersist and it is autowired in persistService?
            persistService.doPersist(householdUpdateServiceCall);
            ...
```

What I'm looking for is how to mock a method (`String result = meterManagementService.getResult()`) inside the `persistService`? For example how to set a value "OK" for `meterManagementService.getResult()`?

Thank you for any advice and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `@MockBean` in your test like this (if `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`)

`@MockBean private MeterManagementService meterManagementService`

It will be mocked and injected.

If you are not using or you cannot use `SpringRunner` use constructor/setter to set your dependencies - there you will be able to provide mocked instances and use it at will.

Comment: Hi, I have @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), it's an old project in Spring I have to maintain. Will check about constructor dependency also the entire configuration is stored in XML files. If someone has some good tutorials about testing in Spring, please let me know.

Comment: `public final class SpringRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner ` so its exactly the same